# Colab and Bigquery: endless 403 errors

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api, google-colaboratory

My goal is to access my BigQuery data in a Colab notebook, but despite this being what seems like a fairly straightforward task I'm getting endless 403 errors.

I've added a service worker to my project and permission it the following ways:

```
BigQuery Admin
BigQuery Data Editor
BigQuery Data Viewer
BigQuery User
Viewer
Editor
```

According to the **Policy Analyzer** each of these is applied to the project and the datasets. I've created an API key and imported that to the Colab. Despite that I get a 403 access denied error each time I run the following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('pathtoapikey.json')

project_id = 'myproject'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)


query_job = client.query("""
   SELECT *
   FROM myproject.mydataset.table_name
   LIMIT 1000 """)

results = query_job.result()
```

Error:

```
Forbidden                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-208d568225a8> in <cell line: 15>()
     13    LIMIT 1000 """)
     14 
---> 15 results = query_job.result()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py in result(self, page_size, max_results, retry, timeout, start_index, job_retry)
   1518                 do_get_result = job_retry(do_get_result)
   1519 
-> 1520             do_get_result()
   1521 
   1522         except exceptions.GoogleAPICallError as exc:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    347                 self._initial, self._maximum, multiplier=self._multiplier
    348             )
--> 349             return retry_target(
    350                 target,
    351                 self._predicate,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, timeout, on_error, **kwargs)
    189     for sleep in sleep_generator:
    190         try:
--> 191             return target()
    192 
    193         # pylint: disable=broad-except

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py in do_get_result()
   1508                     self._job_retry = job_retry
   1509 
-> 1510                 super(QueryJob, self).result(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
   1511 
   1512                 # Since the job could already be "done" (e.g. got a finished job

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py in result(self, retry, timeout)
    909 
    910         kwargs = {} if retry is DEFAULT_RETRY else {"retry": retry}
--> 911         return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
    912 
    913     def cancelled(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in result(self, timeout, retry, polling)
    259             # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
    260             # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 261             raise self._exception
    262 
    263         return self._result

Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern.

Location: US
Job ID:
```

Things I've tried:

1. Deleting all service workers
2. Re-permissioning everything
3. Removing all permissions from all users other than owner, creating
4. New service worker, then adding permissions.
5. Creating new API keys (and updating in colab/etc)
6. Tearing the whole thing down and starting from scratch

Etc. It really seems like this should be a pretty easy permissioning item, but for the life of me I can't find the missing link. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

```
Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern.
```

may indicate that table `myproject.mydataset.table_name` is an external table that is accessing data in a bucket. If that is the case, you'll need to add the following role to your SA for the bucket that is accessed:

```
roles/storage.objectViewer
```

[IAM roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

In our architecture, we have narrowed down to the following BigQuery-roles for Jupyter service accounts (read-only):

```
roles/bigquery.jobUser
roles/bigquery.dataViewer
```

To allow altering data, add
`roles/bigquery.dataEditor`

[BigQuery basic roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-basic-roles)

Answer (score 2):

Are you the owner of the datasource/ set as well? It appears to me that the permission issue is coming from the BigQuery side of things, on a dataset level.

Datasets have child resources such as tables or views, and permissions for these are inherited from the parent dataset. See this [ACLs on datasets document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam) for more information.

Other than the IAM policies which grant access to resources, BigQuery has the ability to provide access on a dataset level to query it, kindly check these documents: [Authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views), [Authorized dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-datasets) and [Authorized UDF](https://cloud.devsite.corp.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#authorized_udfs).

Comment: yeah, good question; yes, I am the owner, they're tables created from CSVs, no child resources (to my knowledge, I suppose there's a world some are auto-created?)